# How to implement client credential flow for application trust in cross tenant of azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

I would like to make call from another API. these two API's must be trusted using azure managed service. To make a call of API2 from API1, token must be generated in API1 and passed in authorization header. This token must be validate in API2. This communication must be cross tenant.
For this I have created two accounts in azure. I have registered application with multi tenant option in both tenant.
Now I am confused how to apply the scope and permissions.
Please help me how to create a token and how it can be validate.
In the same way API2 will make call to API1.

Comment: In your scenario, you have two APIs, right?

Comment: The [OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) should meet your requirements.

Comment: Yes Carl, I have two API's from different tenant, I have readed the documents related authoriation code flow and also client credential flow. Could you please guide me in steps. I am confused how to create token in API1 that will verify in API2. Also clear me end point used to create token and verify that token.

Comment: Did you look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview?

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

According to your description in the question, you have two tenants, with API1 application in tenant 1, and API2 application in tenant 2. Before starting, you need to add the API1 application in tenant 1 as an enterprise application to tenant 2.You need to execute the request in your browser: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={api1 client id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}` Then you need to use tenant 2’s Log in with an administrator account and consent.

Next, you need to add the administrator account of tenant 1 to tenant 2 as a [guest account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).

Next, you need to obtain the access token of the middle layer API1. Please note: According to the requirements of OBO flow, you cannot use the client credential flow to obtain the access token of the middle-tier api. You must use the flow with user login, you can use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). In tenant 1, you need to expose the api of API1, and then add the **client id of API1 application** in **Add a client application**.

[image]

Obtain API1's access token：

1. You need to log in with the administrator account of tenant 1 in the browser and obtain the authorization code.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant 1 id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=a5387724-fd55-4120-88e4-dc8150203dde
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://a5387724-fd55-4120-88e4-dc8150203dde/read
&state=12345
```

2. Redeem token.

[image]

Parse the access token of api 1:

[image]

Next, go to tenant 2 and expose the api of API2, and then add the client id of api 1 to **Add a client application**.

[image]

Finally, use the [OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to obtain an access token for API 2.

[image]

Parse the access token of api 2:

[image]

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks fro your explaination in steps and your valuable time. I have created the API1 in tenant1 and API2 in tenant 2. Trying to register API1 in tenant2 as an enterprise application using following URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={api1 client id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}

Comment: It is showing error    "Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application '53b922a1-206a-4d06-96ab-1f1c3b2b5a38' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account"

Comment: I have registered the user as an guest  user then The error has been changed "Need admin approval
API1
unverified
API1 needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it." Even though  i have logged in as administrator user.

Comment: Please help me to resolve it. I cant see the API1 in tenant2 in Entrprise  Application blade

Comment: Did you use the administrator's consent url and then log in with the administrator account of tenant 2?

Comment: Hi @Carl Zhao,   yes I have used administartor concent url. while login it shows error as mentioned in above comments. I am trying to get  application of tenant1 in Enterprise Application blade of tenant2. But facing errors.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot for me? Did you get a `true` response in the browser?

Comment: Earlier it was showing same window asking permission. I have added group and added users in that group then after I am getting response  "http://localhost:7000/home?admin_consent=True&tenant=766fdd0b-f80b-4056-80f6-aaeaef23b7f3#"  This is tenant id of tenant1 .I have logged into tenant2. Can u please tell me how to upload screen shot.

Comment: I have checked the application not added into Enterprise application blade of tenant2

Comment: Yes Carl. I have mentioned in comment. Please let me know what could be solution.

Comment: This is very strange, I just tried it, and it does appear in tenant 2 Enterprise applications. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfoQ.png

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={tenant 1 web api 1 client id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}  `

Comment: Then use the administrator account of tenant 2 to log in.

Comment: Hi Carl, I have created two azure accounts with free subscriptions. The credential those are used to loogged into the azure portal, same credentials i am using for adminconcent of tenant2

Comment: @Hi Carl, I am using personnel accounts.